# Return the first n letters of a word

Tags: r

Right now I have the following line of code in R:

```
counts = table(unlist(dataTable[, grep('column', names(dataTable))]))
```

and have a data table that looks similar to this:

```
print(dataTable)

 column_1   column_2   column_3
  ball.3     ball.3     ball.3
  NA         ball.1     ball.1
  ball.3     NA         ball.2
  NA         NA         NA      
  ball.2     ball.2     ball.1
  ball.1     NA         ball.1
  disk.1     disk.2     NA
  disk.2     disk.2     disk.3
  disk.2     disk.1     NA
```

This code will currently extract all instances of "ball.1", "ball.2", "ball.3", "disk.1", "disk.2", and "disk.3" and will put them into a table such as the one below:

```
print(counts)

ball.1       ball.2      ball.3      disk.1      disk.2      disk.3
   5            3           4          2           4           1
```

Right now, I am trying to find a way to have grep only look for the first n letters in a world and assign that count to a category. For example, in this data set I do not care so much about ball.1 vs. ball.2 vs. ball.3, but would rather only prefer to have counts of the number of times that the word begins with "ball" or "disk", ignoring whatever comes after those first n=4 letters.

Preferably it would work in a way that I could just focus on looking for the first four letters of any word, so that I would have a data table looking like this:

```
ball         disk
 12           7
```

My reasoning:

I deal with very large data sets containing many long species names. From time to time, somebody may attach a number to the back of a word or leave off/add a letter somewhere. If I can narrow down the search parameter of my code to only search for the first n letters in a name, I will eliminate having to go through .csv files and double check 1000+ rows of names for spelling. I have looked for solutions to this problem, but have only found them in other languages (unfortunately none in C, or I could rig something from that myself)

Comment: Use `substr` or something instead?

Comment: That is perfect. I did not know about that function. Thank you.

Comment: `grep` is not really the best tool for substrings - see @Chris Down's answer for http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96243/show-only-part-of-the-line-found-by-grep-but-not-the-part-that-matches-the-patt (R uses a version of unix grep)

Answer (score 7):

You can try `substr` instead:

```
table(substr(unlist(mydf[, grep("column", names(mydf))]), 1, 4))
## 
## ball disk 
##   12    7
```

You could also use `sub`/`gsub` if you wanted, perhaps something like this:

```
table(gsub("(^.{4}).*", "\\1", unlist(mydf[, grep("column", names(mydf))])))
## 
## ball disk 
##   12    7
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are 2 other solutions that might work depending on your case.

**Total Occurrences of 'Ball' and 'Disk'**

If you want to get the total number of times `ball` and `disk` appear in the data frame, you can use `grep` with `length` to return a single number:

```
> length(grep("^(ball|disk)",unlist(df)))

[1] 12
```

**A More General `substr` Method**

A different take on @Ananda's solution:

```
 table(substr(unlist(df), 1, 4), useNA="ifany")
```

This has 2 advantages:

1. It doesn't care what the column names are. Meaning they don't have to include `column`.
2. It will count `NA` values, so you'll know how many times `NA` occurs.

The result:

```
> table(substr(unlist(df), 1, 4), useNA="ifany")

ball  disk  <NA>
  12     7     8
```

Comment: I feel that this answer makes too many assumptions that the sample data here is directly representative of the OPs actual problem. For example, unlisting the entire `data.frame` assumes that they only have columns named "column_##" in their actual dataset. Similarly, `grep("^(ball|disk)", ...)`, assumes that they are only going to be looking for a small number of known values. Just my opinion....

Comment: Very true, I mostly wanted to try a few things to learn myself. Along the same line of reasoning, your solution assumes they're only interested in columns containing the word `column`.

Comment: ... which is an assumption based on their existing code attempts :-)

Answer (score 3):

This could be done with `sub` by removing the substring that follows the `.`

```
 table(sub('\\.\\d+', '', unlist(dataTable)))
 #
 #ball disk 
 # 12    7
```

Comment: I thought the exact same: `gsub("[.][0-9]*","",x)` but from the other way.

Answer (score 0):

The `stringr` package works well

```
table(apply(dataTable, MARGIN = 1, FUN = stringr::str_sub, 1, 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I've been playing with you might find useful if you decide to keep your data as `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(column_1=c('ball.3', NA, 'ball.3', NA, 'ball.2',
                            'ball.1', 'disk.1', 'disk.2', 'disk.2'),
                 column_2=c('ball.3', 'ball.1', NA, NA, 'ball.2', NA,
                            'disk.2', 'disk.2', 'disk.1'),
                 column_3=c('ball.3', 'ball.1', 'ball.2', NA, 'ball.1',
                            'ball.1', NA, 'disk.3', NA))
```

Use `%like%` is a similar way that you would use `%in%` but functions like 'grep'

```
Find values in 'column_1' containing 'ball' and return a logical vector
DT[, column_1 %like% 'ball']

[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE

Find values in column_1 containing 'ball' and return a table of logical values
DT[, table(column_1 %like% 'ball')]

FALSE  TRUE 
5     4 

Find values in 'column_1' containing 'ball' or 'disk' and create a new column to categorize each value as 'ball' or 'disk'
return a table of counts in each category
DT[, category :=
     ifelse(column_1 %like% 'ball', 'ball',
           ifelse(column_1 %like% 'disk', 'disk', NA))
   ][, table(category)] # this code adds a column 'category' to the DT which is not helpful for multiple columns with identical data.

category
ball disk 
4    3 

Find values in 'column_1' containing 'ball' and return a count
DT[column_1 %like% 'ball', .N]

[1] 4
```

If you have multiple data (i.e. species names) that are repetitive, meaning that the same values are used multiple times, and you just want to see the unique variations you could use `unique`, but this may not be useful if many names are appended with dates or something other than integers.

```
Find unique values in all columns returning a new DT smaller than DT
DT[, lapply(.SD, unique), .SDcols = c('column_1', 'column_2', 'column_3')]

> DT[, lapply(.SD, unique), .SDcols = c('column_1', 'column_2', 'column_3')]
  column_1 column_2 column_3
1:   ball.3   ball.3   ball.3
2:       NA   ball.1   ball.1
3:   ball.2       NA   ball.2
4:   ball.1   ball.2       NA
5:   disk.1   disk.2   disk.3
6:   disk.2   disk.1   ball.3
```

If you find a value that is either incorrect or not useful you may replace it with a new value which would simplify searches.

```
DT[column_1 == 'ball.3'] <- 'new.value'


   column_1  column_2  column_3
1: new.value new.value new.value
2:        NA    ball.1    ball.1
3: new.value new.value new.value
4:        NA        NA        NA
5:    ball.2    ball.2    ball.1
6:    ball.1        NA    ball.1
7:    disk.1    disk.2        NA
8:    disk.2    disk.2    disk.3
9:    disk.2    disk.1        NA
```